Geometry question about the center of an inscribed circle
I have a geometry problem, I actually solved it but I still want to find a shorter and better way
problem: let pointed triangle ABC (AB<AC), The bisector of angle A intersects BC at D, E lies on segment BC such that CE=BD. The external bisector of angle A intersects the line through D perpendicular to BC at F. I is midpoint of FD, EI $\cap$ AD=M. EF intersects the line through M perpendicular to BC at K. prove that I is incenter of KBC


Your problem statement does not match your figure

@RobinSparrow i dont understand, can you point that out

For example: "I is midpoint of EF". $I$ isn't even on line $EF$ in the diagram. It goes off from there. Read it and check the diagram - you should see that in no way is $I$ close to the center of $KBC$.

@RobinSparrow oh sorry my bad, I is midpoint of FD

Please edit your question to correct the statement - people may not read the comments, and it cannot be solved in its present form with an incorrect problem statement. Further, you ask us to prove that I is the center of KBC. If your figure is to scale, this cannot possibly be true.

@RobinSparrow okay, i have fix it

Draw 2 tangents from KT,KR to (I) cutting BC at B',C'. According to the familiar problem, we have B'D=C'E.
i prove that AD is the bisector of angle B'AC'
we have (DL,AF)=D(DL,AF)=D(WK,MF)=-1 so PL is tangent from P to (I) (P=DD $\cap$ AF)
on the other hand we have (LD,TR)=-1 so TR passes through P.
so AD perpendicular AP and (PD,B'C')=-1 $\Rightarrow$ AD is bisector of B'AC'.
now we prove that (B',C')=(B,C). We see that A,D,E are fixed so i prove that There is only one set of 2 points (X,Y) sastify AD is bisector of XAY and XB=EY, In this step I use the coordinate method and it's not too long. If you have another solution, please contribute
